# different URL opening the same

Tags: android, url, android-studio, expandablelistview

So guys, in my app, i build a menu, with an expandablelistview, and one of the groups have 4 childs, one that open a facebook page, another a website page, a youtube page and a google+ page. But No matter where i click all of them opens the google+ page, and i dont see why. Here's the code:

```
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            int pos = childPosition;
            //clique em contatos
            if(groupPosition == 5){
                switch(pos) {
                    //Clique em emails e contatos
                    case 0:
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Contatos.class);
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            //clique em hiperligacoes
            if(groupPosition == 3){
                switch(pos) {
                    //click no facebook
                    case 0:
                        Intent browserFace = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/moises.transporte.passageiros?fref=ts"));
                        startActivity(browserFace);
                    //click no site
                    case 1:
                        Intent browserSite = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://moises-transportes.pt/"));
                        startActivity(browserSite);
                    //click no youtube
                    case 2:
                        Intent browserYoutube = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXeHbISNnc0eLCPnTeolxLg"));
                        startActivity(browserYoutube);
                    //click no google+
                    case 3:
                        Intent browserGoogle = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/111005531753993560637/about"));
                        startActivity(browserGoogle);
                }
            }
```

Can you guys help me finding why is this happening ?

Comment: Does the problem depend on the order of which one is clicked first when you test?

Comment: No, i already got an answer bolow, was missing the breaks.
But thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break`.

Use break after every case statement. Orelse all the cases after the correct one is executed one after the other.

```
     if(groupPosition == 3){


             switch(pos) {
                    //click no facebook
                    case 0:
                        Intent browserFace = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/moises.transporte.passageiros?fref=ts"));
                        startActivity(browserFace);
                        break;
                    //click no site
                    case 1:
                        Intent browserSite = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://moises-transportes.pt/"));
                        startActivity(browserSite);
                        break;
                    //click no youtube
                    case 2:
                        Intent browserYoutube = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXeHbISNnc0eLCPnTeolxLg"));
                        startActivity(browserYoutube);
                    //click no google+
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Intent browserGoogle = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/111005531753993560637/about"));
                        startActivity(browserGoogle);
                        break;
                }
     }
```

Comment: You are right, thank you so much, i totally forgot. 
Can you just answer another question reallating to this piece of code also. With that code i have the URL's opening in an outsite browser, chrome. Is there a way that i can make this open in the app? Like, if i used master detail flow url's opens in the app, but here i'm using expandablelistview, is there a way i can do it ?

Comment: You need to use a WebView for that. Look it up on google on how to use it. There are plenty of good tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to break your cases in switch. Write `break;` before you write the next case for each. Also, add a default case.

Comment: You are right, thank you so much, i totally forgot. 
Can you just answer another question reallating to this piece of code also. With that code i have the URL's opening in an outsite browser, chrome. Is there a way that i can make this open in the app? Like, if i used master detail flow url's opens in the app, but here i'm using expandablelistview, is there a way i can do it ?